How to use onesignal and flask site?
I'm trying to subscribe myself to onesignal using a simple python flask app in my local machine. I have the pop up that asks me if I want to subscribe and then the browser asks me if I want to allow notifications (which I click "allow"). Then, I check the OneSignal dashboard and I can't find my device subscribed (the count is always 0).
What I'm doing wrong?
This is my app structure:
/my_project
  /templates
    index.html
  /static
    OneSignalSDKWorker.js
  app.py

This is my app.py:
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=6868,debug=True)

And this is index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OneSignal Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/web/v16/OneSignalSDK.page.js" defer></script>
    <script>
        window.OneSignalDeferred = window.OneSignalDeferred || [];
        OneSignalDeferred.push(function (OneSignal) {
            OneSignal.init({
                appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>


</html>

